# Cron (through whenever gem) not running

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I am following [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/164-cron-in-ruby-revised).

1. I added whenever gem in Gemfile and ran bundle install
2. have put this code in config/schedule.rb file

   ```
   every 1.minute do
     command "rm #{path}/tmp.txt"
   end

   every 2.minutes do
     command "rm #{path}/tmp.txt"
   end
   ```

I am trying to remove the tmp.txt file but it is not getting deleted. What am I missing ?

Comment: Do you encounter this problem on your local machine or on your production server?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The actual work is done by server's `crontab` command. "Whenever" gem is nothing but a nice tool to help you write cron commands and update easily.

Maybe you forget to update crontab? Try this

```
whenever --update-crontab store
```